# Spacing issue with Asana Math font

Tags: spacing, unicode-math, asana

I have an issue with the spacing when using the Asana Math font. When I put an integral in the exponent the lower bound overlaps with the integral. This does not happen when I am using other Open Type fonts such as Garamond Math. Do anyone know how to fix this?

The document compiles with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}

\begin{document}

\[
    e^{-\int_{0}^{T}r(t)dt}
\]  

\[
    \exp\left(-\int_{0}^{T}r(t)dt\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Inserting a thickspace `\;` gives a good spacing: `e^{-\int_{\;0}^{T}r(t)dt}`. Try thinspace `\,`, too.